# dataTables - filter/search only in selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a question. Is there any possibility in jQuery dataTables plugin to only filtering rows with specific class?
For example: I got a table and I want to filter only rows with `searchable` class. The rest rows stays as they is.
Is this even possible?

```
<table class="dataTable">
  <tr class="searchable">
    <td>text to search</td>
    <td>text to search</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something else</td>
    <td>something else</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="searchable">
    <td>text to search</td>
    <td>text to search</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>something else</td>
    <td>something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

I'm thinking to write my own plugin, but I never do that before.
Something like:

```
getFilterInput
table.each(tr).function(){
if(row.hasClass(searchable){
    //do filtering
}else{
    //leave row alone
}
```

Anyone does something like that and can give me a clue where to start?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this. Did you found the solution?

Comment: @SritejaSugoor Sorry, but I honestly don't remember. It was 6 years ago and the project was shut down in mid-2014 I think. But I'm guessing not, otherwise, I would add an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use selector like this: `$('.searchable')`

```
$('tr').not('.searchable').hide();
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but unfortunately I need those rows to display.

Comment: you need to display .searchable row or others?

Comment: I need to display both, but I want to filter only `searchable`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use a hidden column that says whether that row is searchable or not, then when you need to find those specific rows, you just search that particular column.

The way you're trying to leverage classes in your markup will almost certainly require that you modify DataTables.js and/or develop your own plugin.